# CPU usage of iphone game..Is this an ok value?

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, cpu-usage

This is a screen shot of my game when launched on my iphone 4, as you can see at the begining there is a very high usage of cpu. I'm trying to preload assets and use global @properties for every reused object ( to avoid to call them like -->  [self childNodeWithName:@"object"];
But I'm concerned about the beginning, Is there other ways to make it less cpu expensive?
And for the rest of the graphic, is ok my cpu usage? what is the max usage allowed for games without crash-been refused by apple?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: You are free to use 100% CPU if you like. There is no point making your app less cpu expensive. If there is lag in the interface however, simply move your processing to the background so the interface is smooth.

Comment: how do I move the processing to the background?

Comment: I would disagree with @JackWu that "there is no point making your app less CPU expensive." Making your program less CPU expensive is almost always a good idea, especially on mobile platforms. 38% seems pretty reasonable to me, but if you see ways to make it less, by all means, do that! It extends the user's battery life, which is great.

Comment: Check out apples documentation on Grand Central Dispatch(GCD) here:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1

Comment: Another tutorial that is great can be found on RayWenderlich here http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

Comment: @user1118321 Yes I agree there are optimizations that can be done. But are they worth it? Unless you are creating the next Infinity Blade I would say no.

Comment: Startup will always chew up the CPU.  You just don't want an app (especially a game) that's a battery hog over the long haul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the large spike at the beginning is due to preloading assets, as you mention. You seem to average about 40% CPU usage which is perfectly fine!